# Unknown Error using mosquitto on a new computer

Tags: mosquitto

Today i installed mosquitto on a diffrent pc and im getting an error, that i personally cant do anything with.

I have googled for the past 2 hours without any luck regarding the issue.

when calling

```
mosquitto_pub.exe -t "something" -m "something"
```

i receive this error message:

"Unable to connect (Lookup error.)."

From what i have been reading the usual Errors come with codes that let u track the issue but this is so vague i have no idea what the problem could be.

I have set it up on 3 other pcs without any issues and the command works without any problems.

Now on this new pc, the error comes constantly.

Has anyone else encountered this, using mosquitto in the past and knows a way of fixing it?

All Pcs are running windows 7 64bit, and similar hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I identified the problem myself.

The network connection was disabled which led to that error.